# How to do multiple repetitive functions after click each of two buttons

Tags: jquery

I have 2 buttons and a "div".
after the clicking on the each of "next" or "back" buttons , I want the "div" to slide left pr right;
It is working for the first time I click "next" and first time for "back".
after clicking on "back" button , the code seems not running.
now why this happens? and how can I fix this?

```
 $(function () {
       $('.next_btn1').click(function () {
         $('#productExample').animate({
       left: 444
     });
   });

   $('.back_btn1').click(function () {
     $('#productExample').animate({
       right: 0
     });
   });
```

Comment: Can you show your html/css? hard to tell what happening

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heres a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/wwWaldi/h15jxrb4/10/

```
 $(function () {
    $('.next_btn1').on('click', function () {
        $('#productExample').animate({ left: 444 });
    });

    $('.back_btn1').on('click', function () {
        $('#productExample').animate({ left: 0 });
    });
});
```

In order to go back to the original position you just set left back to 0